# CentOS internet connectivity issue

Tags: centos

I am using 2 systems with i5 processor and CentOS 7 operating system. I wanted to install Teamviewer hence upgraded the system with

`yum update`

One of the two systems is working fine. But another system is exhibiting internet connectivity issue. The system is connected to my mobile internet using usb tethering.

I searched for many forums and tried the suggestions like updating `resolv.conf` with

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

The icon on the desktop is showing connecting status.

`nmcli dev status`

Above command displays following output

`enp0s20f0u1  ethernet  connecting(getting IP configuration)  wired connection`

The system where internet is working fine exhibits above status but browsing happens conveniently.

If you have any troubleshooting steps please let me know.

Comment: Has your DHCP server run out of addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Nmcli (network manager command-line interface) is a command-line utility used to control the NetworkManager daemon which is used to configure network interfaces.

Here are a couple of suggestions, but by no means definitive answers:

- Try different dhcp client
- Disable dnsmasq plugin
- Delete [connection configurations and reconnect](https://technicalexplore.com/ethernet-connected-but-no-internet/)
- Disable NetworkManager from creating a default wired connection
- Try WICD network manager
- Examine /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf file